# Separar miles y decimales en campo input con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentando separar con miles y decimales una cifra en un campo input mientras se van tecleando los números utilizando jquery.
Ejemplo:
18.340,34
He utilizado varias plugins y creado algunos códigos pero no he podido lograrlo, necesito ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: ¿que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour].  Tambien considera [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar [ECMAScript Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NumberFormat) - texto en español.

El [soporte en los navegadores](https://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization) es bastante bueno.

Una [lista de códigos de divisa en formato XML](https://www.currency-iso.org/dam/downloads/lists/list_one.xml)

```js
var num = 18340.34;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(num));
```

#### Actualización

El OP comenta:

> para mi pais Venezuela me dice que le cambie por currency:'VES' y me se muestra 18.340,34 VES y debería ser 18.340,34 Bs. ¿No existe alguna forma de modificarlo?

Lo único que se me ocurre es un apaño con `replace`:

```js
var num = 18340.34;

var cadena = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-VES', { style: 'currency', currency: 'VES' }).format(num);

cadena = cadena.replace('VES','BS')
console.log(cadena)
```

Comment: Amigo ha funcionado, pero ahora en donde dice currency:'EUR' para mi pais Venezuela me dice que le cambie por currency:'VES' y me se muestra 18.340,34 VES y debería ser 18.340,34 Bs. ¿No existe alguna forma de modificarlo?

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta. Por favor échale un vistazo.

Answer (score 0):

Por si alguien lo necesita, estuve buscando la solucion al tema, y encontre una solucion, por decirlo de cierta manera es un error de "Tipado" por el Locale() de Venezuela es `es-VE` pero el que acoge Intl es `es-Ve`

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-Ve', {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'VES',
            minimumFractionDigits: 2
        });
        return formatter.format(data);
    // esto resulta Bs.S 723.657.019,22
```

esto resulta de que hay que Cambiar `es-VE` ó `es-VES` por `es-Ve`. este ultimo es el que mas me ha funcionado. Espero les sirva